# Content and Structure Tool Error: SmtMoveTitle List does not exist

Tags: content-type, content-and-structure

I am trying to relocate a subsite on SharePoint 2013 using the Content and Structure tool.

When I try to move the aforementioned subsite, I receive this error:

**"SmtMoveTitle
List does not exist.
The page you selected contains a list that does not exist.  It may have been deleted by another user."**

Does anybody know how to remedy this error? It does not occur on every subsite. It just so happens to occur on the one I need to move. Classic lol